# Best way to do 10,000 inserts in a SQL db?

Tags: sql, notifications

What happens is whenever i upload media onto my site; everyone will get a notification. Each person can click a box to remove and it will be gone from their msg queue forever.

If i had 10,000 people on my site how would i add it to every person msg queue? I can imagine it takes a lot of time so would i opt for something like a filesystem journal? mark that i need to notify people, the data then my current position. Then update my position every 100 inserts or so? I would need a PK on my watcher list so if anyone registers in the middle of it my order will not be broken since i'll be sorting via PK?

Is this the best solution for a mass notification system?

-edit-

This site is a user created content site. Admins can send out global messages and popular people may have thousands of subscribers.

Comment: What database software are you using? Is it running on a single server or in a master/slave setup or as a cluster, or … ? Please provide more details.

Comment: Wim: I actually dont have any details. Currently i have a prototype using C# and sqlite as the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 10000 inserts into a narrow many to many table linking the recipients to the messages `(recipientid, messageid, status)` is slow, I expect you've get bigger problems with your design.

This is the kind of operation I wouldn't typically even worry about batching or people subscribing in the middle of the post operation - basically:

Assuming `@publisherid` known, `@msg` known on SQL Server:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO msgs (publisherid, msg)
VALUES(@publisherid, @msg)
SET @messageid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO msqqueue (recipientid, messageid, status)
SELECT subscriberid, @messageid, 0 -- unread
FROM subscribers
WHERE subscribers.publisherid = @publisherid

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just record for each user which notifications they have seen- so the set of notifications to show to a user are ones created before their "earliest_notification" horizon (when they registered, or a week ago...) minus the ones they have acknowledged. That way you delay inserting anything until it's a single user at once- plus if you only show users messages less than a week old, you can purge the read-this-notification flags that are a week or more old.

(Peformance optimisation hint from my DBA at my old job: "business processes are the easiest things to change, look at them first")

Comment: That sounds like something i would do to copy a struct (on change, not right away). But in this case would this not be worse? 10,000 will *continuously* poll me to see if i have updated?

Comment: I don't see that it's worse--- how were you going to drive notifying the users even if you did insert into a notification table when the message was created-- you must have been polling that?

Yes, each user will be doing something like "select ... from message where message.created > :horizon and not exists (select 1 from message_read where message_read.user = :user and message_read.message_id = message.message_id)". Indices on message(created) and message_read(user_id, message_id) should make that a simple query.

Comment: I would select the user msg queue and nothing else. I guess my post is bad, i am not the only one who can upload media. Its a user content site like youtube. There will be a few admin that can post global media and global msg along with popular people who could attract dozens of subscribers. Thats several places to poll instead of your msg center. I was planning to do the inserts when the author triggers it (upload of sends out the msg/media).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just let the database take care of things it is well capable of and designed to do.  Insert and manage data.  Don't try and do it in code, just write the SQL to insert the data all in one go.  10000 rows is a diddle for all real databases.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO inserting records may not be the most efficient solution to this problem. Can you use a  client side cookie to store whether the user removed the notification or do you have to keep track of this even if they clear cookies? If you upload a new video the app can just compare the cookie with the new video record id and decide to show or hide the notification based on whats stored in the cookie. This will save you a ton of database inserts, and keeps most heavy lifting on the client.

Comment: I would have to keep track of it on the server but isnt this just moving inserts to selects since now 10000 need to poll me instead?

Comment: You still have to do selects in any case when they load the page to see if their record exists to indicate they closed the notification, unless i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres, you can use the COPY command which is the fastest method of them all:

```
COPY tablename (col1, col2, col3) FROM '/path/to/tabfile';
```

where *tabfile* is a TAB-separated file with lots of entries. This will fail if there are some UNIQUE constraints, though, and there are duplicates in the file.